# Moment of inertia "about ? axis"

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

I'm just trying to calculate how fast a 2D polygon should spin given x amount of energy. To do this, I figured I'd split my shape up into triangles, calculate the MoI for each around the polygons center of mass and add them all up. Only problem is, I don't know math or physics so its been a pretty crappy ride.

Main thing I'm trying to figure out is, MoI for right triangles is often given as these 2 equations:
Ix = b * h ** 3 / 36
Iy = h * b ** 3 / 36
and described as "about x/y axis".

What does that mean? I don't understand moment of inertia outside the context of things rotating around a point, how can you rotate around an entire axis unless you're breaking into 3D?

Also, I find a lot of materials on integrals and how those equations came to be but its all chinese to me. All I really want is just one example of somebody calculating the MoI caused by an arbitrary triangle hinged around an arbitrary point but nobody does that.

I've seen some triangles calculated but since there are 2 equations, they get 2 results that mean.. what? No clue, all explanation stops there. Also, I can't always have right angled triangles with adjacent/opposite aligned to x or y axis, actually that almost never happens in reality. I can cut triangles in half to make right angles but can I also rotate the resulting triangles around their centers of mass to align their axi?

Comment: If you just want to work in a plane, the relevant moment of inertia is $I_z$, and it is always equal to $I_x + I_y$. This is the perpendicular axis theorem.

Comment: I’m curious... If you don’t know math or physics, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: No physical object rotates around a point. There is always an axis of rotation, although it may not stay in a fixed direction.

Comment: In 2D, things rotate around points. Anyway, I finally figured it out thanks to the hint by knzhou. its just Ix + Iy + <distance from triangle com to shape com> ** 2 * <mass of triangle>, the triangle can have whatever orientation as long as its right angled, b and h are either of the non-hypotenuse sides.